# Uniswap: Why is there an intermediary when swapping?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, swaps, 1inch-dex-aggregator

I am trying to understand why sometimes when a wallet buys a token the Uniswap pool sends the token through an intermediary address before it gets sent to the buyer.

Here's an example of such transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa485503529131872384e4e1411caa36ba27eab40d8e8ded1a717bc90b37db786

The buyer of NFY token is: 0x004baEac693AAC11dcD1D7139338D32FbD87898A

But the pool (0x146D3401B6a41122Bd318ba676A01c44cB0795E2)
sends tokens to intermediary address (0xb3C9669A5706477a2B237D98eDb9B57678926f04) first.

Most of the time when a wallet buys a token the pool directly sends it to them, so why is this case different?